# How to ship a necessitas or qt project with a preloaded database

Tags: android, qt

Is there any way to add a preloaded sqlite database to a necessitas or qt project? I try to copy it directly to /data/data/my_project/files7 in the emulator and I dont have problems, but when I tried to copy it to and Samsung Galaxy Gio It said that I dont have permission, is there anyway to solve this without rooting the device or includiong the database in the project?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can add any files to your apk file.
To do this just add these strings to project file:

```
deployment.files = cfg.init
deployment.path = /assets/data/data/org.kde.necessitas.example.<package_name>/files
INSTALLS += deployment
```

There are two restriction: all deployement files are READONLY, and they can be opened only by  using AbsolutelyPath.

So, I have solved these problems by adding some code to the program:

```
if (!QFile::exists("cfg.db"))
{
    QFile dfile("/data/data/org.kde.necessitas.example.<package_name>/files/cfg.init");
    if (dfile.exists())
    {
        dfile.copy("cfg.db");
        QFile::setPermissions("cfg.db",QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner);
    }
}
```

That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but how about using this : [Qt Resource System](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_Resource_Editor_with_Qt_Creator).